# Weird str right after execution

Tags: python

I've been playing around with some code and recently found this issue out, once this code runs it returns "None" right under the players name and health, I've been trying to figure out why and changed a lot of the code but the issue still remains, does anyone know why this might be? much appreciated!

```
import random
import math
import os
import time

def return_health(name, health, maxHealth, healthDashes):
  dashConvert = int(maxHealth/healthDashes)
  currentDashes = int(health/dashConvert)
  remainingHealth = healthDashes - currentDashes

  healthDisplay = '-' * currentDashes
  remainingDisplay = ' ' * remainingHealth
  percent = str(int((health/maxHealth)*100)) + "%"

  print(name+" "+"|" + healthDisplay + remainingDisplay + "|")
  print("                       " + percent)

class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, maxhealth, health, healthdashes, offense, jutsu1, jutsu2, jutsu3):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = maxhealth
        self.health = health
        self.healthdashes = healthdashes
        self.offense = offense
        self.jutsu1 = jutsu1
        self.jutsu2 = jutsu2
        self.jutsu3 = jutsu3


class Jutsu():
    def __init__(self, name, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage


## Jutsu's
Rasengan = Jutsu("Rasengan", 15)
Rasenshuriken = Jutsu("Rasenshuriken", 30)
VermillionRasengan = Jutsu("Vermillion Rasengan", 50)
Chidori = Jutsu("Chidori", 15)
OnxyChidori = Jutsu("Onxy Chidori", 30)
SusanoArrow = Jutsu("Susano's Arrow", 50)

## Player's
Naruto = Player("Naruto Uzumaki", 100, 100, 20, 10, Rasengan, Rasenshuriken,
                VermillionRasengan)
Sasuke = Player("Sasuke Uchiha", 100, 100, 20, 10, Chidori, OnxyChidori, SusanoArrow)


def fight(player1, player2):
    os.system("clear")
    while True:
        if player1.health <= 0:
            os.system("clear")
            print(player1.name + " has been defeated.")
            time.sleep(3)
            break
        elif player2.health <= 0:
            os.system("clear")
            print(player2.name + " has been defeated")
            time.sleep(3)
        else:
            print(return_health(player1.name, player1.health, player1.maxhealth, player1.healthdashes))
            print(return_health(player2.name, player2.health, player2.maxhealth, player2.healthdashes))
            print(player1.name + "'s turn.'")
            print()
            print("Choose your move!")
            print("1. Attack" + " : " + str(+player1.offense))
            print("2. " + player1.jutsu1.name + " : " +
                  str(+player1.jutsu1.damage))
            print("3. " + player1.jutsu2.name + " : " +
                  str(+player1.jutsu2.damage))
            print("4. " + player1.jutsu3.name + " : " +
                  str(+player1.jutsu3.damage))
            choice = input("> ")
            os.system("clear")
            if choice == "1":
                print(player1.name + " has attacked " + player2.name +
                      " for " + str(player1.offense) + " damage.")
                player2.health -= player1.offense
            elif choice == "2":
                print(player1.name + " attacked " + player2.name + " with " +
                      player1.jutsu1.name + " for " +
                      str(player1.jutsu1.damage) + " damage.")
                player2.health -= player1.jutsu1.damage
            elif choice == "3":
                print(player1.name + " attacked " + player2.name + " with " +
                      player1.jutsu2.name + " for " +
                      str(player1.jutsu2.damage) + " damage.")
                player2.health -= player1.jutsu2.damage
            elif choice == "4":
                print(player1.name + " attacked " + player2.name + " with " +
                      player1.jutsu3.name + " for " +
                      str(player1.jutsu3.damage) + " damage.")
                player2.health -= player1.jutsu3.damage

            time.sleep(2)
            os.system("clear")

            if player2.health <= 0:
                os.system("clear")
                print(player2.name + " has been defeated.")
                time.sleep(3)
                break
            else:
                print(player2.name + " : " + str(player2.health))
                print(player1.name + " : " + str(player1.health))
                print(player2.name + "'s turn.'")
                print()
                print("Choose your move!")
                print("1. Attack" + " : " + str(+player2.offense))
                print("2. " + player2.jutsu1.name + " : " +
                      str(+player2.jutsu1.damage))
                print("3. " + player2.jutsu2.name + " : " +
                      str(+player2.jutsu2.damage))
                print("4. " + player2.jutsu3.name + " : " +
                      str(+player2.jutsu3.damage))
                choice = input("> ")
                os.system("clear")
                if choice == "1":
                    print(player2.name + " has attacked " + player1.name +
                          " for " + str(player2.offense) + " damage.")
                    player1.health -= player2.offense
                elif choice == "2":
                    print(player2.name + " attacked " + player1.name +
                          " with " + player2.jutsu1.name + " for " +
                          str(player2.jutsu1.damage) + " damage.")
                    player1.health -= player2.jutsu1.damage
                elif choice == "3":
                    print(player2.name + " attacked " + player1.name +
                          " with " + player2.jutsu2.name + " for " +
                          str(player2.jutsu2.damage) + " damage.")
                    player1.health -= player2.jutsu2.damage
                elif choice == "4":
                    print(player2.name + " attacked " + player1.name +
                          " with " + player2.jutsu3.name + " for " +
                          str(player2.jutsu3.damage) + " damage.")
                    player1.health -= player2.jutsu3.damage

                time.sleep(2)
                os.system("clear")


fight(Naruto, Sasuke)
```

Comment: You could next time try to **debug** the code (for example using  https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html), then you'd be able to narrow down what causes the problem easily by executing the program step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return_health` returns nothing (`None`) and that's what you print, because you called `print(return_health(...))`.

If you expect the function to print stuff on its own (it currently does), better call it `print_health` and not `return_health`, and just call it without  also `print`ing its (empty) return value.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following line

```
print(return_health(player1.name, player1.health, player1.maxhealth, player1.healthdashes))
```

You are asking python to print the result of the `return_health` function. The `return_health` function doesn't actually return anything so the result of the function is `None`.

You don't need the `print` at the start of this line since the `return_health` function already prints the health information.

Also, it would be better Object Oriented Programming, to make this functionality part of the `Player` class.

Consider the below change

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, maxhealth, health, healthdashes, offense, jutsu1, jutsu2, jutsu3):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = maxhealth
        self.health = health
        self.healthdashes = healthdashes
        self.offense = offense
        self.jutsu1 = jutsu1
        self.jutsu2 = jutsu2
        self.jutsu3 = jutsu3
    def showhealth(self):
          dashConvert = int(self.maxhealth/self.healthdashes)
          currentDashes = int(self.health/dashConvert)
          remainingHealth = self.healthdashes - currentDashes

          healthDisplay = '-' * currentDashes
          remainingDisplay = ' ' * remainingHealth
          percent = str(int((self.health/self.maxhealth)*100)) + "%"

          print(self.name+" "+"|" + healthDisplay + remainingDisplay + "|")
          print("                       " + percent)
```

Then when you want to output the health of the player you just call something like

```
player1.showhealth()
```

You could also have an "Attack" method for the class.

```
def attack(self, other_player, chosen_jutsu):
    ....
```

If player1 is attacking player 2, this would look like

```
player1.attack(player2, choice)
```